# Why does list comprehension not filter out duplicates?

Tags: python, list, filter, duplicates, list-comprehension

I have a workaround to the following question. That workaround would be a for loop with a test for inclusion in the output like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def rem_dup(dup_list):
    reduced_list = []
    for val in dup_list:
        if val in reduced_list:
            continue
        else:
            reduced_list.append(val)

    return reduced_list
```

I am asking the following question, because I am curious to see if there is a list comprehension solution.

Given the following data:

```
reduced_vals = []
vals = [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 0, 0]
```

Why does

```
reduced_vals = = [x for x in vals if x not in reduced_vals]
```

produce the same list?

```
>>> reduced_vals
[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 0, 0]
```

I think it has something to do with checking the output (`reduced_vals`) as part of an assignment to a list. I am curious, though as to the exact reason.

Thank you.

Comment: You can get very close using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6197827/355230) answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list comprehension creates a new list, while `reduced_vals` points to the empty list all the time during the evaluation of the list comprehension.

The semantics of assignments in Python are: Evaluate the right-hand side and bind the resulting object to the name on the left-hand side.  An assignment to a bare name *never* mutates any object.

By the way, you should use `set()` or `collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys()` to remove duplicates in an efficient way (depending on whether you need to preserve order or not).

Comment: How would I include collections? I just tried to; it imported; but I got an error >>> collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys(color)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'collections' is not defined I'm using Python 2.7.x

Comment: @octopusgrabbus: `import collections`

Comment: >>> import collections
>>> collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys(color)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OrderedDict'

Answer (score 4):

You are testing against an empty list.

The expression is evaluated in full first before assigning it as the new value of `reduced_vals`, which thus remains empty until the full list expression has been evaluated.

To put it differently, the expression `[x for x in vals if x not in reduced_vals]` is executed in isolation. It might help if you view your code in a slightly modified fashion:

```
temp_var = [x for x in vals if x not in reduced_vals]
reduced_vals = temp_var
del temp_var
```

The above is the moral equivalent of directly assigning the result of the list expression to `reduced_vals`, but I have more clearly separated assigning the result by using a second variable.

Answer (score 4):

In this line: `[x for x in vals if x not in reduced_vals]` there's not a single value that is *not* in `reduced_vals`, as `reduced_vals` is the empty list `[]`. In other words, nothing gets filtered and all the elements in `vals` get returned.

If you try this:

```
[x for x in vals if x in reduced_vals]
```

The result is the empty list `[]`, as *all* the values *are not* in `reduced_vals` (which is empty). I believe you have a confusion with how the filtering part works in a list comprehension: you see, the filter only selects those values which make the condition `True`, but it won't prevent duplicate values.

Now, if what you need is to filter out duplicates, then a list comprehension is not the right tool for the job. For that, use a set - although it won't necessarily preserve the order of the original list, it'll guarantee that the elements are unique:

```
vals = [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 0, 0]
list(set(vals))
> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the elements in the list comprehension are not assigned to `reduced_vals` until the entire list has been constructed. Use a `for` loop with `.append()` if you want to make this work.

Comment: That's already what's happening in the original code (one without the OP's 'workaround')

Answer (score 0):

Because `reduced_vals` is not changing during evaluation of the list comprehension.