# A pythonic way to remove all instances of an element without generating a new list

Tags: python, list, data-structures

There are many questions similar to this ([here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python)) but the solutions I've seen use list comprehension or filter and those ways generate a new list (or a new iterator in the case of filter in Python 3.x). There are solutions that remove instances by modifying the list itself ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629198/python-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python?rq=1), [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurences-of-a-value-from-a-python-list)), and those would be my last resort. However, I am asking to see if there a more elegant ("Pythonic" as another question calls it) way of doing it.

Why I am disregarding solutions that generate a new list: I am iterating over a collection of lists, and Python allows me to modify the "current" list I am iterating over, but not to replace it entirely:

```
>>> ll= [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [4,5,6]]

>>> for l in ll:
        if l[0] == 2:
            l = [10]
>>> ll
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6]]   #replacement didn't happen

>>> for l in ll:
        if l[0] == 2:
            l.remove(2)
>>> ll
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5, 6]]   #modification succeeded
```

Comment: So you want to remove elements from a list, without creating a new list or modifying the existing list?  That excludes everything.

Comment: Haha. Sorry, I see I didn't clarify (I'll edit). No, of course I am looking for a way to modify the list just a more pythonic way than, for example, the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurences-of-a-value-from-a-python-list

Comment: Do you know what functional means?

Comment: Good point; I edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use slice assignment to replace all list *elements* instead of the list itself:

```
for l in ll:
    if l[0] == 2:
        l[:] = [10]
```

The `[:]` part turns this into slice assignment; instead of replacing the reference `l` points to, you replace *all* elements contained *in* `l` with the new list.

Demo:

```
>>> ll= [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [4,5,6]]
>>> for l in ll:
...     if l[0] == 2:
...         l[:] = [10]
... 
>>> ll
[[1, 2, 3], [10], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Now I can make use of list comprehension to remove all instances of an element through modification, not generating a new list: >>> ll= [[1,2,3], [2,3,4,2], [4,5,6]]
>>> for l in ll:
 if l[0] == 2:
  l[:] = [x for x in l if x!=2]

  
>>> ll
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5, 6]]

Comment: @AnasElghafari: Or you could just do `ll = [filter(lambda x: x != 2, el) for el in ll]`