# Remove the object being iterated over from list

Tags: python, list

Consider:

```
fooList = [1, 2, 3, 4] # Ints for example only, in real application using objects

for foo in fooList:
    if fooChecker(foo):
        remove_this_foo_from_list
```

How is the specific `foo` to be removed from the list? Note that I'm using ints for example only, in the real application there is a list of arbitrary objects.

Thanks.

Comment: It's worth noting the contents of [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2629240/172176), which would suggest that building a new list is more efficient than modifying one in-place. If you need to do it in-place `my_list.remove(my_item)` is particularly bad, because it's an O(n) lookup - use `del my_list[index]` instead.

Comment: @Aya but then you have to iterate by index (or use `enumerate()` - still ugly) - hence my suggestion of just building a new list then assigning back if you need to modify the existing list. Generally, of course, one can just build a new list and forget the old one.

Comment: @Lattyware Indeed. See also my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, you just don't want to do this. Instead, construct a new list instead. Most of the time, this is done with a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw):

```
fooListFiltered = [foo for foo in fooList if not fooChecker(foo)]
```

Alternatively, a generator expression (my video linked above covers generator expressions as well as list comprehensions) or [`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#filter) (note that in 2.x, `filter()` is *not* lazy - use a generator expression or `itertools.ifilter()` instead) might be more appropriate (for example, a large file that is too big to be read into memory wouldn't work this way, but would with a generator expression).

If you *need* to actually modify the list (rare, but can be the case on occasion), then you can assign back:

```
fooList[:] = fooListFiltered
```

Comment: Since the OP's `fooChecker()` returns `True` to remove an item from a list, you could also mention `itertools.ifilterfalse(fooChecker, fooList)`.

Answer (score 8):

Iterate over a shallow copy of the list.

As you can't modify a list while iterating over so you need to iterate over a shallow copy of the list.

```
fooList = [1, 2, 3, 4] 

for foo in fooList[:]: #equivalent to list(fooList), but much faster
    if fooChecker(foo):
        fooList.remove(foo)
```

Comment: +1, this is the other way to do it. Just to explain, the copy is needed in order to ensure the list doesn't change while you are iterating over it, as that will cause unwanted behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

Use `filter`:

`newList = list(filter(fooChecker, fooList))`

or

```
newItems = filter(fooChecker, fooList))

for item in newItems:
    print item # or print(item) for python 3.x
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter

Comment: -1 - This will produce the list of all values that should be removed - the exact *opposite* of what was requested.

Comment: So tell me, how hard is it to negate a condition? Given the fact that `filter` can produce really readable code?

Comment: Indeed I recognize my mistake, but I think it's not fundamental and the OP can figure it out by himself.

Comment: Then change you answer to include that note - given it reverses the operation performed, it's pretty important.